# adding entity from one manager to another in breeze

Tags: breeze

I've created 2 entity managers using the same metadata and want to add some entity from manager1 to manager2.

I'm getting an Error: **Cannot attach this entity because the EntityType and MetadataStore associated with this entity does not match this EntityManager's MetadataStore.**

here the function that creates managers:

```
function createLocalManager(servName) {
    var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: servName,
        hasServerMetadata: false
    });

    var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore(); 
    metadataStore.importMetadata(app.metadata); // initialize it from the application's metadata variable

    return new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService,
        metadataStore: metadataStore
    });
}
```

here I get my error:

```
em1 = createLocalManager('serviceName1');
em1.createEntity("Picture");

em2 = createLocalManager('serviceName2');
em2.addEntity(em1.getEntities()[0]);
```

Also I've checked and this

```
em1.metadataStore == em2.metadataStore
```

return false!!! Why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Breeze provides a method called `entityManager.createEmptyCopy()` to create a copy of the original EntityManager with the same metadata.

```
var em2 = em1.createEmptyCopy();
```

Secondly, since you're using a different `DataService`, you have to set `em2` dataService manually.

```
var ds = new breeze.DataService({
   serviceName: 'serviceName2',
   hasServerMetadata: false
});

em2.setProperties({dataService: ds});
```

Finally, the correct way to share entities among multiple entityManagers is to use `entityManager.exportEntities` and `entityManager.importEntities`

```
var picture = em1.createEntity("Picture");
var entitiesToExport = [picture];
var exportedEntities = em1.exportEntities(entitiesToExport);
em2.importEntities(exportedEntities);
```

This topic of creating multiple managers and sharing data among them is also documented in detail on http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers

Hope this helps.

Comment: And what should I do If I need to append entity from one manager to another non empty manager? The problem is in identical entity keys. How can i say to breeze to append with unique key?

Comment: I've added a comment in your other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914060/what-is-the-right-way-to-append-entity-from-one-manager-to-another-in-breeze