# What is the right way to append entity from one manager to another in breeze?

Tags: breeze

What is the right way to append entity from one manager to another?
Straight forward attempts result in overwriting entities or in warning about the same entity key...

```
var entity = em1.getEntities()[0];
em1.deattachEntity(entity);

// assume em2 already has entities
em2.attachEntity(entity);
```

I believe there should be some in-build functionality for **appending** entries to another non empty manager or for generating an unique key for selected manager.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
I did read [the documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/exportimport) and tried to do it via exportEntities and exportEntities:

```
    var entity = em1.getEntities()[0];
    var export = em1.exportEntities([entity], false);
//here em2 already has entity with the same key as entity that I want to add
    var import = em2.importEntities(export, { mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.Disallowed });
```

This gives me an error: **A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' prevents Picture:#Macaw.Whitelabel.WebAPI.Models--1 from being merged**

I really don't understand how to append entities....

**UPDATE2:**
I did discover that manually assigning id of the attached entity solves the problem and error disappears. 
Is there a way to make it not manually but using breeze?

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding entity from one manager to another in breeze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893191/adding-entity-from-one-manager-to-another-in-breeze)

Comment: @PW Kad, it was also my question and it don't answer the current question!

Comment: have you looked at the docs?  They specifically go over the correct way to export and import entities from one manager to the other.  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/exportimport

Comment: @PW Kad, yep i did read docs. See update of my second try with export/import

Comment: If the second entityManager already has an entity with the exact same primary key why would you want to import it?

Comment: @Qvatra, you're almost in the right direction, except, you're using the wrong MergeStrategy. What you want is MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges or MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges depending on your scenario. See http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MergeStrategy.html

Comment: @PW Kad,  because i want to import DIFFERENT entity from different manager with different data. It just appears that entity keys are the same..

Comment: @DenisK, Yep, I've read that too. I use MergeStrategy.Disallowed on purpose - I want to append entity and not overwrite!!

Comment: @DenisK, see update2 to the post. The id problem appears after page refresh. em2 imports previously saved entities and I need to add new entities from em1 (that have same id due to refresh) to em2.

Comment: Qvatra you are missing the underlying point - you should **not** be assigning the same UniqueId to multiple entities and if you are that is a design flaw, don't try to work around it, fix the underlying issue.  You can use autoGeneratedKeyTypes but again just if you read the docs thoroughly you will understand it better than if we post a code snippet workaround http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/AutoGeneratedKeyType.html

Comment: I agree with PW Kad. It appears that you have a design flaw if you have contextually different entities but with the same primary key. One suggestion is to re-think if you really do need multiple EntityManagers. The following page, http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers, lays down some scenarios on why you need multiple managers and how to go about achieving them.